# Information about the setDataDefinedProperty

Tags: qgis, symbology, api, c++

In the QGis C++ API v1.6 there is a function called setlowerValue to set a value for a specific Symbol

In my application i use QGis C++ API 2.8.2, i try to understand how the function setDataDefinedProperty works ?
Is it the same ?
In my application I have a list of symbol corresponding to a depth of the sea and a specific color, I want to categorized that

How can i porceed in 2.8.2 ?
Here is my code :

```
lrenderer = QgsFeatureRendererV2::defaultRenderer( QGis::Polygon );
QList<QgsSymbolV2*>         lSymbols    = lrenderer->symbols();
QList<QgsSymbolV2*>         lSymbolsToRender    = lrenderer->symbols();
QStringList lListValue;
lListValue  << "0" << "3" << "5"<< "10";

for(int i = 0 ; i < lListValue.size() ; i++) {
    QgsSymbolV2* newsymbol = lSymbols.at(0);
    QgsSymbolLayerV2List  lSymbolLayerList = newsymbol->symbolLayers();

    QgsSymbolLayerV2 * lSymbolLayer;
    lSymbolLayer = lSymbolLayerList.at(0);
    lSymbolLayer->setFillColor(QColor(115, 182, 239)); // couleur de remplissage bleu
    lSymbolLayer->setColor( QColor(125, 137, 140) ); // couleur courbe de niveau
    lSymbolLayer->setDataDefinedProperty("Value",lListValue.at(i));
    //newsymbol->setLowerValue( QString::number(i) ); // Version 1.6 old code
    //((QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2*)lrenderer)->insertValue( lListValue.at(i), newsymbol ); // Version 1.6 old code
    newsymbol->insertSymbolLayer(lListValue.at(i).toInt(), lSymbolLayer);
    lSymbolsToRender.append(newsymbol);
}
```

There is no information in the API DOC onLine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not want different symbol layers (they will be painted on top of each other).

You probably want to look into `QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2` which lets you define multiple categories with a different symbol for each.

`setDataDefinedProperty` is for defining a style property based on a feature attribute like the color defined by a field with color values (e.g. `#3e5da2`). In addition to this, you can also insert a QgsExpression which generates a value. So with a statement like `CASE WHEN "x">10 THEN '#ff0000' ELSE '#00ff00' END CASE` you could get the same effect.

Comment: so if I understand in my symbollayer I had to use QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2 to have different color